# Hosts are not found by server after restart and require manual input of DNS server to work

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, network-interface, resolv.conf

My Raspbian server "forgets" it's hosts after resrtat.

The only solution that I have found is to manually run:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf'
```

However, it is erased on restart and requires me to input it again.
I want to make this as unattended as possible.

Since I use it as both a print server and as a IRC core, it must have a static IP.

My current /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.64
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

address 192.168.0.64
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

I have attempted to add google dns server to this file at the end, but did not work.

Additionally, when my server starts, there is an error message:

```
[FAIL] Not running dhcpcd client because /etc/network/interfaces defines some interfaces that will use a DHCP client.
```

I am sure it is relates, but not sure how.

Please help me find a solution that will be a permanent fix, so that I can restart my server remotely without having to connect to it and manually run:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf'
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove the excess from your file.  Comment out everything from the `wpa-roam` (with a `#` symbol at the start of each line) onwards.

---

`/etc/resolv.conf` should not be changed by you on modern distros.  The first couple of lines of the file on my Raspbian (and others) says:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Therefore, read `man resolvconf` to see how it's updated - it could be your network scripts, or Network Manager.

If you're not using Network Manager, then chances are you'll need to add the relevant stanza to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
auto eth0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.64
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Note the `dns-namservers` entry.

If you're using Network Manager and a graphical desktop environment, then you can probably add the DNS servers in there.

If you're not using a graphical desktop environment but you are using Network Manager then the `nmcli` tool may help you configure your DNS resolvers:

```
$ sudo nmcli con mod eth0 ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8"
```